# Treatment vs control extrapolation of results

Tags: regression, interpretation, probit

Apologies in advance for any vagueness in the question. Please let me know if clarification is needed.

If a control group has a 33% payback rate on a loan, and an experiment finds that a treatment group had an 8% increase in probability to pay back a loan, can I simply do .33*.08 to extrapolate what the payback rate of a loan would potentially be in a treatment group?

Results were gathered using a probit regression. [The study in question can be found here.](https://www.povertyactionlab.org/sites/default/files/publications/260%20Reminders%20for%20Savings%20Uganda%20May%2011.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Table 3](https://www.povertyactionlab.org/sites/default/files/publications/260%20Reminders%20for%20Savings%20Uganda%20May%2011.pdf#page=26) reports probit index function coefficients, which are not particularly useful on their own. But it is easy enough to work out how they got the marginal effects and the predicated rates of repayment. Focusing on the first specification, it means that in this simple model,

$$\Pr(Repayment) = \Phi(-0.760)=0.22362729$$

if someone has the control experience.

If treated with the cash back, then this rises to $$\Pr(Repayment) = \Phi(-0.760 + 0.262)=0.30924202.$$

For the other two treatments, you would replace the second coefficient with the one corresponding to that treatment.

This means that about 3 out 10 repay with this treatment, versus about 2 out 10 in the baseline. The 0.085 is the difference between these two probabilities, which has the units of [percentage points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage_point):

$$\Phi(-0.760 + 0.262) - \Phi(-0.760)=0.08561473.$$

It is not multiplicative, but an additive change in probability of repayment. Here $\Phi(.)$ is the standard normal CDF function.

Comment: Simple to understand and effective at explaining. Many thanks!

Comment: Would you know how to calculate the CDF function in R by chance?

Comment: @JonathanRauscher Try `pnorm()`.